# Questions involving inheritance, Deallocation of pointer objects and when to do so

Tags: c++, pointers, object, inheritance

I am in a programming class currently, and find that the teacher is not great at conveying *how* to use the concepts we are taught. I've searched multiple questions about my topic but couldn't really get much help from it. Sorry if some of this seems similar.

1) When dealing with parent/child objects, say you have a class VehicLot which adds a vehicle objects child(motorcycle object, car object, truck object) and the number of those objects into a `vector <Vehicle*> lot`. In scenarios such as these, I cannot seem to understand what's going on. I'm unsure on if I deallocate properly as well. (I'm coming up with this off of the top of my head, so sorry if this seems like a dumb example. This is close to a scenario I had trouble with a few weeks ago though.)

```
void VehicLot::addVehic(int typeNum, int numVehic) {
    if(typeNum == 1){
        Car* newCar = new Vehicle();
        for(int i = 0; i < numVehic; i++)
            lot.push_back(newCar);
    delete newCar;
    newCar = NULL;
    }
}
```

So, in this code, does this properly add a Car (which would be type #1 in this) object so the vector of vehicles? If so, did I properly deallocate memory as well? Sorry if any of this code isn't correct in other ways, I kind of came up with this on the fly to simulate areas that confuse me. Are new objects created to temporarily "use" the class functions to store data in other things? To try and explain that further, is the reason I would make these temporary vehicle objects solely to add those objects into a vector that can actually hold the data for use later on? These problems lead into question 2.

2) One of my biggest problems in Computer Science so far has been seg faults. After some research I've seen that this is normally due to accessing memory that isn't "there." Is that a reasonable way to describe it? Can you give any tips as to what I should search for relating to seg faults? Since my concept of deleting pointers seems a bit fuzzy, I'm assuming my problem lies in not properly deleting pointers/objects.

Since I am taking a course in this, I should add that I don't know many of the "shortcuts" that I've seen on here. I need to understand my problem, but also be capable of doing things in the way that's expected of me. I really would appreciate any help on this, as I've done a large amount of research but just cannot manage to understand where I must improve.

Comment: If a beginner course teaches manual memory management then it's probably not very good.

Comment: I'm not necessarily a 'beginner', I would say. I guess I would consider it the class for those who know basics and are now expanding on more. I've done various things in the past such as functions,recursion, and all the stuff you could consider the "backbone" of making a program. It's getting more detailed, which I enjoy, but the class has been seemingly more difficult due to the teacher (or the way he teaches compared to how I learn, at least).

Comment: *One of my biggest problems in Computer Science so far has been seg faults* -- It isn't the Computer Science that is the issue -- you're using a language, `C++`, that relies on the programmer to know, top to bottom, how to handle dynamically allocated memory properly.  Java has no such "segmentation faults" to deal with.  If this course is C++, and if they want to take you down this path, a better assignment would be to attempt to build your own working `vector` or `string` class, not these "one-off" attempts of using `new` and `delete`.

Comment: I agree that there are ways they could better the problems given, but I'm stuck with the questions they give me, so I need to know how to solve them the way "they" want me to do it. I personally believe it's just making it harder for me but oh well. Is the way I've done it at least correct?

Comment: It isn't correct in that all you did was store the same pointer value in the vector.  What good does that do?  Also, you've `delete`d that pointer value, so now your vector `lot` consists of pointer values that are all invalid, so the vector itself is now useless to you.

Comment: Is `Car` derived from `Vehicle` or does `Vehicle` derive from `Car` in your example above? It seems like it is the latter, which would be odd.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was under the impression that the code above would store the car objects into the vector, then they would be 'saved' in that vector to be used later on, and I could delete them to save memory while still having those addresses in the vector.

Comment: @Corristo Vehicle is the "parent" class, car is the "child." If I made a larger example there would be vehicle, then it's child classes of car, truck, motorcycle etc. Did I do this incorrectly?

Comment: @bake In your code you're creating Vehicle objects and try to assign them to a `Car` pointer, that is not going to work. It should be the other way around: `Vehicle* car = new Car{};`.

Comment: Ah, that's a pretty big problem I've been doing then. I've been swapping them. So it's Parent* name = new Child(); Thanks!

Comment: @bake You declared a `vector<Car*>`.  So in that loop, you now have a vector with all the entries being the same pointer value.  You allocated once, and in a loop, just assigned the same pointer to each of the vector's entries.  You have not created different cars.  Then you `delete` this pointer, so now your vector is populated with a single pointer value in all the entries, and that pointer value is now invalidated due to your `delete` call.  Look at the logic flow in the program you posted -- this should have been obvious.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh! yeah wow I'm dumb. What an idiotic mistake to make. Thanks for *pointing* that out. I don't think I often make that mistake of putting objects outside of the loop, on the bright side. Deleting the pointer I do often though, so that makes sense.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry for berating you with questions. But this raises another question in my head then. When should I delete the pointer and set it to null? I was told to always dereference the pointers I make.

Comment: You `delete` the pointer when no longer needed.  When is "no longer needed"?  That is up to you and your application, since you took on the job of memory management.  All I can say is that undeleted dynamically allocated memory results in a memory leak, and deleting the same pointer value two or more times is a double-deletion error.

Comment: So is it safe to say that you dont need to delete a pointer in every function that it's used? When I was told "you must always delete a pointer that you created" I presumed that meant if I used a pointer in a function, I'd delete it in that function. Quite the stretch looking back at it.

Comment: Memory management means just that.  Once you play the role of memory manager, you have to figure out or know beforehand how, when, and where the objects will be created and their lifetimes and to make sure no mistakes made like memory leaks, double-deletion errors, accessing invalidated memory, etc.  There is no automatic garbage collection like in other languages to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *After some research I've seen that this is normally due to accessing memory that isn't "there."*

This means you are accessing memory outside of what the compiler allocated for your program.

When you declare an array, let's say `int arr[3]`, your compiler reserves 3 spaces in memory, each being 8 bytes long. Now, this memory space can be anywhere; the memory block right after this may be allocated for some internal computer process. When you accidentally try to access it, (let's say `arr[5]`), you are looking into memory that should be out of your bounds. If that memory block is empty, the program will continue running normally. However, if it is reserved for another process, you run into a seg fault.

That is why it is called *undefined behaviour*; you may run into a seg fault if your code touches inaccessible memory, or your program may just continue running if it trods on empty memory. Both are wrong, though, your array shouldn't go out of bounds.

Hope this helps

Comment: So if I get a seg fault it could be due to perhaps an array or vector I have being accessed out of it's bounds? Thanks, I'll have to make sure to check for stuff like that in the future. Is that the most common reason for seg faults?

Comment: @bake, out-of-bound access and use-after-free are most common causes for segmentation faults

Comment: "use after free"?

Comment: @bake `char *ptr = new char[10]; delete [] ptr; delete [] ptr;` -- double deletion error on the pointer value that was just deleted.

Comment: Based on my experience, that's mostly where I've faced seg faults

Comment: @bake `int* i = new int(5); delete i; return *i;`, here you're using the memory location where `i` points to after it has been free'd.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ah, thank you. Would this error only be within the scope of that pointer? So if I made a function with a *ptr then delete it, but create a *ptr in another function and delete it, that is not double deletion, right?

Comment: @bake -- It is the value of the pointer that matters.  If the value is `0x1234ABCD` and you delete that value twice in succession (assuming that in-between delete calls, `0x1234ABCD` wasn't assigned again), that is undefined behavior, more likely a seg fault.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh, that makes sense. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your questions, but they've been answered already, so good luck. If my answer helped/worked for you, here's what u can do to appreciate it: [What should I do if someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

In you're example code you create a single `Vehicle` object, then you copy `numVehic` pointers to it into the vector, and then you delete the object pointed to by all these pointes in the vector. So all the pointers in the vector point to memory that is no longer valid.

Assuming you want *independent* Carsin the vector, what you should do instead is

```
void VehicLot::addVehic(int typeNum, int numVehic) {
    if(typeNum == 1){
        for(int i = 0; i < numVehic; i++) {
            lot.push_back(new Car{});
        }
    }
}
```

Without changes to the destructor of the class that contains the `lot` member variable, this will lead to memory leaks. So you need to adjust the destructor of that class to loop over all elements in the vector and call `delete` on them, which would look similar to this

```
~ClassThatContainsLotVariable::ClassThatContainsLotVariable() {
    for (auto vehicle : lot) {
        delete vehicle;
    }
}
```

The best solution, however, is to change the definition of `lot` to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>>`, that way you don't need to care about memory management at all - the compiler-generated default deconstructor of the class holding the `lot` member variable will automatically do the cleanup for you. Moreover, it will help identify places where you're accidentally sharing the same object (which is what happened in your example, as pointed out before), because you can't copy a unique_ptr.

Comment: But if I want to add a specific object type into the vector, wouldn't it be something like `lot.push_back(new Car());`     also, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @bake That's why I asked if `Car` derives from `Vehicle` or if it is the other way round :) From you example code it seemed like `Car` is the base class. It is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks again. This is starting to actually make sense.